# Why can I cat /dev?

Tags: macos, cat

I can `cat /dev`, I can `ls /dev`, I can't `less /dev`. Why does `cat` let me `cat` this directory but no other directories?

[image: Picture of this behaviour in zsh.]

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, here's the output and `neofetch` for your information :)
https://i.imgur.com/3azpnDt.png

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Historically (up to V7 UNIX, or around 1979) the `read` system call worked on both files and directories. `read` on a directory would return a simple data structure which a user program would parse to obtain the directory entries. Indeed, the V7 `ls` tool did exactly this - `read` on a directory, parse the resulting data structure, output in a structured list format.

As filesystems got more complex, this "simple" data structure got more complicated, to the point where a `readdir` library function was added to help programs parse the output of `read(directory)`. Different systems and filesystems might have different on-disk formats, which was getting complicated.

When Sun introduced the Network File System (NFS), they wanted to fully abstract away the on-disk directory structure. Instead of making their `read(directory)` return a platform-independent representation of the directory, however, they added a new system call - `getdirents` - and banned `read` on network-mounted directories. This system call was rapidly adapted to work on all directories in various UNIX flavours, making it the default way to get the contents of the directories. (History abstracted from https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/ReaddirHistory)

Because `readdir` is now the default way to read directories, `read(directory)` is usually not implemented (returning -EISDIR) on most modern OSes (QNX, for example, is a notable exception which implements `readdir` as `read(directory)`). However, with the "virtual filesystem" design in most modern kernels, it's actually up to the individual filesystem whether reading a directory works or not.

And indeed, on macOS, the `devfs` filesystem underlying the `/dev` mountpoint really does support reading (https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/miscfs/devfs/devfs_vnops.c#L629):

```
static int
devfs_read(struct vnop_read_args *ap)
{
        devnode_t * dn_p = VTODN(ap->a_vp);

    switch (ap->a_vp->v_type) {
      case VDIR: {
          dn_p->dn_access = 1;

          return VNOP_READDIR(ap->a_vp, ap->a_uio, 0, NULL, NULL, ap->a_context);
```

This explicitly calls `READDIR` if you try to read `/dev` (reading files under `/dev` is handled by a separate function - `devfsspec_read`). So, if a program calls the `read` system call on `/dev`, it'll succeed and obtain a directory listing!

This is effectively a feature that is a holdover from the very early days of UNIX, and which hasn't been touched in a very long time. Part of me suspects that this is being kept around for some backwards compatibility reason, but it could just as easily be the fact that nobody cares enough to remove the feature since it isn't really hurting anything.

Comment: Probably the latter, seeing as it has been removed from most directories.

Answer (score 36):

*Less* is a text file viewer, *cat* is a tool for copying arbitrary data. So *less* performs its own checking to make sure you're not opening something that will have massive amounts of data or behave very strangely. On the other hand, *cat* has no such checking at all – if the kernel lets you open something (even if it's a pipe or a device or something worse), *cat* will read it.

So why does the OS allow *cat* to open directories? Traditionally in BSD-style systems *all* directories could be read as files, and that was how programs would list a directory in the first place: by just interpreting dirent structures stored on disk.

Later on, those on-disk structures began to diverge from the dirent used by the kernel: where previously a directory was a linear list, later filesystems began using hashtables, B-trees, and so on. So reading directories directly wasn't straightforward anymore – the kernel grew dedicated functions for this. (I'm not sure if that was the main reason, or if they were primarily added for other reasons such as caching.)

Some BSD systems continue to let you open all directories for reading; I don't know whether they give you the raw data from disk, or whether they return an emulated dirent list instead, or whether they let the filesystem driver decide.

So perhaps macOS is one of those operating systems where the kernel allows it *as long as* the filesystem provides the data. And the difference is that `/dev` is on a `devfs` filesystem that was written to allow this in the early days, while `/` is on an APFS filesystem that omitted this feature as unnecessary in modern times.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually done any research on BSDs or macOS. I'm just winging it.

Comment: This seems to make sense. Are there any other sections of storage that differ from the standard OS filesystem? I assumed `/etc` would, so I used that as my benchmark.

Comment: On the contrary, generally /etc is just a regular folder containing regular files. There _may_ be other virtual filesystems though – run `mount` or `/sbin/mount` to see what's currently mounted where.

Comment: You're right!
See this: https://i.imgur.com/pcVpo1o.png

Comment: This is really neat @grawity, https://i.imgur.com/8QuR0FK.png

Comment: Well, directly reading a _disk_ is fairly normal operation because disks just have a flat structure anyway (this is how you can make an .iso image of a CD).

Comment: @grawity: I wonder what's something worse :) than opening a device, any malicious examples? ^^

Comment: @haboutnnah Your screenshot confirms that `/dev` is a virtual file system using the `devfs` driver whereas `/etc` is part of the `/` file system using the `apfs` driver. So the reason `cat` will read one and not the other is a difference between the `apfs` and `devfs` drivers.